# In Powershell, how do I create a PatchOperation that adds AWS IAM authorization to an existing API Gateway Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I want to run a PowerShell script in an AWS Lambda that will update an API Gateway endpoint to require IAM authorization. The API Gateway is auto generated from the swagger generated by another application (.NET Core C#).

I've completed some code that is getting me close, but I am getting an error that I'm not sure how to resolve. Here's what I have so far:

```
$patchOperation = New-Object -Type Amazon.APIGateway.Model.PatchOperation
$patchOperation.Path = '/ResourceMethods/PUT/AuthorizationType'
$patchOperation.Value = 'AWS_IAM'
$patchOperation.Op = 'add'
Update-AGResource -RestApiId $ApiId -ResourceId $resource.Id -PatchOperation $patchOperation
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Invalid patch path  '/ResourceMethods/GET/AuthorizationType' specified for op 'add'. Must be one of: []
```

The desired result is that the API Gateway endpoint specified by the IDs will be updated to require IAM authorization when using the verb GET. Ideally, the operation will be idempotent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by using the network tab in my browser debugger to see the values sent to the server. The structure for the PatchOperation object I want is:

```
{"op":"replace","path":"/authorizationType","value":"AWS_IAM"}
```

I also determined this was not a great approach. We are generating the OpenAPI doc with [SwaggerGen](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen). We can use an OperationFilter to add the authentication to the endpoint like so:

```
public class ApiGatewayIntegrationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        operation.Extensions.Add("x-amazon-apigateway-auth", new ApiGatewayAuth
        {
            Type = "AWS_IAM"
        });
    }
}
```